# The loop doesn't continue and the program exits too soon

Tags: loops, assembly, x86-16

The D array should contain the elements placed on even positions in S, and after that the ones placed on odd positions. In the end the D array should look like 1,3,5,2,4, but the code below only makes it 1,3,5,0,0. I verified, the instruction `mov si, 1` executes once and then the program exits.

```
assume ds:data,cs:code

data segment
  S db 1,2,3,4,5
  len equ $-S 
  D db len dup(0) 
data ends

code segment
start:
  mov ax, data
  mov ds, ax
  mov si, 0 
  mov di, 0 
  mov cx, len 
repeat:
  mov al, S[si] 
  mov D[di], al
  inc di
  add si, 2 
  cmp si, len
  JGE instruction 
  dec cx
  CMP cx, 0
  JNE repeat
  JE sf
instruction:
  mov si, 1
sf:
  mov ax, 4C00h
  int 21h
code ends
end start
```

Comment: `D[0] = S[0] = 1, D[1] = S[2] = 3, D[2] = S[4] = 5` and after this `di = 3`, `si = 6`. `si` >= `len` so code jumps to `instruction`
`si = 7` and program exits. Also `dec cx` will automatically set `ZF = 1` if `cx = 0`, so `cmp cx,0` can be removed.

Comment: Ooops, I wrote `si = 7`. Should be `si = 1`.

Comment: If You add `mov cx,2` in `instruction:` and jump back to `repeat:` code will continue adding values to `D`... `D[3] = S[1] = 2, D[4] = S[3] = 4`. Try to add `cmp si,3`, `jz sf` in `repeat:`

Comment: Or actually move `je sf` after `cmp si, len`. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the code again and I noticed that some parts can be changed or removed.

1. Loop counter is in `cx`. I dont know if this is good practice but
   I only used `si` for `repeat1` and `conditional jumps`. So I removed all code connected to `cx`.
2. I moved instruction `JE sf` after `cmp si, len` because in case of odd values, `si (index of S)`, is always even.
   Program copies `1`,`3` and `5` to `array D` and this conditional jump isn't true for index `si = 0, 2 and 4`.
3. In 3rd iteration `array D` looks like this `D = 1 3 5`, `di = 3` and `si = 6`. Code goes through conditional jumps to `instruction` label.
   Your code changes `si`, `si = 1`, so You wanted to do the right thing, change `index of S array` and copy rest of the numbers.
   I added `jmp repeat1`, `si` and `di` are correct so program copies rest of the array S.
4. Iteration 4:

   `D[3] = S[1] = 2`
   `di = 4`
   `si = 3`

   Iteration 5:

   `D[4] = S[3] = 4`
   `di = 5`
   `si = 5`

   And here `si = 5` so program copied all the values and jumps to exit label `sf`.

```
assume ds:data,cs:code

data segment
  S db 1,2,3,4,5
  len equ $-S 
  D db len dup(0) 
data ends

code segment
start:
  mov ax, data
  mov ds, ax
  mov si, 0 
  mov di, 0 
  
repeat1:
  mov al, S[si] 
  mov D[di], al
  inc di
  add si, 2 
  cmp si, len
  jb repeat1
  je sf  

instruction:
  mov si, 1
  jmp repeat1

sf:
  mov ax, 4C00h
  int 21h
code ends
end start
```

Comment: You wrote some explanation in comments under the question, but forgot to include it in your answer.  A code block with no comments doesn't make a good answer, especially not to a debugging question where someone wants to learn what they did wrong and why you changed whatever you changed.

Comment: For readabilities sake, I think you should remove those 5 lines that you commented out with `;`. And please also shorten the trio `JE sf` `JG instruction` `jmp repeat1` to the more efficient pair `JL repeat1` `JE sf`.

Comment: @SepRoland Manual says `JL` is for signed values, maybe I should use `JB`? Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: I suggested the `JL` instruction purely because you were already using the `JG` instruction that is also for signed operation. For my taste, I do prefer to use `JB` because the quantity that we are dealing with here is an unsigned offset SI. If we kept the signed instructions, it would only start to go wrong after some 32768 bytes. Not very likely, wouldn't you say.